# Why must ".text(x)" and not ".text = x" be used in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assigning like this

```
$('#myelement').text = 'some text';
```

has no effect visually.  Is the above ignored by jQuery?

Instead, it should be

```
$('#myelement').text('some text');
```

Comment: [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) is a function, not a property.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I'm not sure what else to tell you. You cannot assign a variable to a function like this.

Comment: Short answer: earlier versions of JavaScript do *not* have getters/setters or "accessor" properties (they were formally added in ES5). Thus jQuery does not take advantage of such and only uses setter/modifier functions.

Comment: @user2864740: nice edit to title. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment in Claudio's message, you are actually replacing the `test()` function within the collection. Since the next time you call `$('#myelement')` a new collection is created, you probably will never notice it, but if you store the collection, you'll see the problem:

```
<span id="myelement">stuff</span>

var mye = $('#myelement');
mye.text = 'nonsense';
mye.text("nonsense");
```

Given that code, the span text will not be changed.  Comment out the middle line and it will be.

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesCurran/FV86a/1/)

Comment: Excellent example.  I may change the accepted answer since now I don't believe it is ignored.  Basically, if you assign to the function, you render that function useless?  At least that is what I see based on your output.

Comment: Yes, but only in that transient collection.

Comment: I don't think this is transient.  It looks as though the effect is permanent on the text() function (it's rendered useless).  Destroying the related element and recreating likely resets everything though.

Answer (score 2):

It's ignored because `text` is a jQuery function, so you cannot use it as a property.

See the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/text/

To be more precise, you cannot use it as a property because you are working with a jQuery object that wraps a DOM element, not the DOM element itself.

Comment: Clarify "ignored".  Aren't you replacing the function with a string?

Comment: No because if you do it in console on this very page and call text() again. It works as normal

Comment: @Huangism It is still not ignored although it may seem like it - this is due to `text` being resolved through the [prototype] and `$()` returning a different jQuery object each time. Compare with `x = $('#myelement'); x.text = "foo"; x.text("bar")`, which will throw an exception.

Comment: @Huangism It overwrites the `text` method of the current collection.

Comment: @user2864740 I don' know what you mean with the compare syntax at the end

Comment: @undefined can you give me an example of what happens?

Comment: @Huangism "Run this code and see what happens" :)

Comment: @Huangism In this case: "TypeError: string is not a function".

Comment: @user2864740 oh I see, I was running `$('#header').text = "foo"; $('#header').text();`

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that jQuery selectors can return a list of elements in which you would work with.

Example:

```
$('.foo').text('updated');
```

Would update every element with the class `foo` and set it's text.

Since you are always working with a list in jQuery (even if it is a list of one) it makes more sense to interact with the items via methods.